# Install horovod on MacOS

Tags: macos, tensorflow, pip, mpi, horovod

After installing horovod via `pip3 install horovod`

I get an error:

```
ImportError: Extension horovod.tensorflow has not been built: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/horovod/tensorflow/mpi_lib.cpython-37m-darwin.so not found
If this is not expected, reinstall Horovod with HOROVOD_WITH_TENSORFLOW=1 to debug the build error.
```

Also  tried

```
pip3 uninstall horovod
HOROVOD_WITH_TENSORFLOW=1 pip3 install horovod

pip3 uninstall horovod
HOROVOD_WITHOUT_MPI=1 pip3 install horovod
```

but get the same error.

Comment: What about `pip3 install tensorflow && HOROVOD_WITH_TENSORFLOW=1 pip3 install horovod --no-binary=horovod`?

Answer (score 2):

One tricky thing about Pip is that you need to specify `--no-cache-dir` to prevent it from reusing its "cached" version of the package (in your case, compiling Horovod with different installation flags.  So try something like this:

```
HOROVOD_WITHOUT_MPI=1 HOROVOD_WITH_TENSORFLOW=1 pip3 install --no-cache-dir horovod
```

Specific to macOS, you need to make sure `libuv` is installed before installing Horovod with Gloo (without MPI):

```
brew install libuv
```